# firewall profile to adapter mapping

Tags: windows, firewall

I am developing WCF service which needs to accept port 9817 TCP connections. To do that I added inbound rule for 9817 port and selected public profile network.

Now, first connection to service fails with EndpointNotFoundException which basically means that client wasn't able to connect to service. However after turning off firewall, making first connection and then turning it back on - connections are being accepted.

I understand that there may be issue in WCF service itself or DNS resolving, but would like to ask two questions since I'm not that strong in firewalls:

1) if some firewall rule is set for, say, public profile and network adapter is associated with domain profile, this rule won't be applied, right?

2) If same rull is applied for public profile, and adapter is associated with all (public, domain, private) profiles - will that rule be matched?

Win2008R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A network connection (notice I didn't say adapter) may be associated with only one network profile at a time. It isn't possible for a network connection to be associated with more than one network profile simultaneously.

A firewall rule may be enabled for a specific firewall profile or for all firewall profiles, which means it will apply to connections associated with any network profile (Domain, Private, or Public).

A network connection may be associated with different network profiles depending on where it's connected. If it's connected to the domain network and the machine is domain joined then the connection will be associated with the Domain network profile and so the Domain firewall profile will be in effect. If the machine is connected to  a wifi network in a coffee shop then the connection will be associated with the Public network profile and so the Public firewall profile will be in effect. Same machine, same adapter... connected to different network types and with different network and firewall profiles. If your firewall rule is enabled for all firewall profiles then it will be in effect for all network profiles.

So the answer is a bit opposite to your question. A network connection can be associated with only one network profile, but a firewall rule may be enabled for all firewall profiles and applied to each type of network profile.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731634(v=ws.11).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I was thinking that one network connection could be associated with multiple profiles, but after running `Get-NetConnectionProfile` in powershell I understood I am wrong